# How to prevent the creation of struct array in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I'm trying to make a struct like this

> a =
>
> ```
> a: {'aa'  'aaa'}
> b: {'bb'}
> ```

It's ok to assign the cell value to each field.

```
a=[];
a.a = {'aa','aaa'};
a.b = {'bb'};
```

But if I do like this

```
a=struct('a',{'aa','aaa'},'b',{'bb'});
```

the result is a struct array

> > > a =
>
> 1x2 struct array with fields:
>
> ```
> a
> b
> ```
>
> > > a(1)
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> a: 'aa'
> b: 'bb'
> ```
>
> > > a(2)
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> a: 'aaa'
> b: 'bb'
> ```

What's the correct way to make such a struct using `struct()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [documented behavior](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html#description):

> `s = struct(field,value)` creates a structure array with the specified
>   field and values. The `value` input argument can be any data type, such
>   as a numeric, logical, character, or cell array.
>
> If value is a cell array, then `s` is a structure array with the same dimensions as `value`. Each element of `s` contains the corresponding
>   element of `value`. For example, `s = struct('f',{'a','b'})` returns
>   `s(1).f = 'a' and s(2).f = 'b'`.

There really isn't a wrong way to do it, either option is perfectly fine. If you'd like to use `struct` you will need to nest your cell array:

```
a = struct('a', {{'aa','aaa'}}, 'b', {'bb'});
```

Which produces:

```
a = 

    a: {'aa'  'aaa'}
    b: 'bb'
```